# how to write multiple queries in a single table with single uery

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `bundle` with the following data
`slotno` `item`
A, item-a-1
A, item-a-2
A, item-a-3
B, item-b-1
B, item-b-2

I need help to get the output as follows
A, 3
B, 2

Thanks inadvance...

Comment: Try: `SELECT slotno, COUNT(item) FROM bundle GROUP BY slotno;`.

Comment: Great, Thank you soooooo much.

Comment: i am trying with count(*), it is giving total of all items

Comment: See [3.3.4.8 Counting Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) and [12.19.1 Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Answer (score 1):

SELECT slotno, COUNT(*) FROM bundle GROUP BY slotno;